# QuickFIX/J — strategy to resend all messages in a sequence (full day recovery)

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

Our project (server/acceptor side) wants to implement recovery from communication failures. This particularly includes responding to message of `MsgType.RESEND_REQUEST` type with `BeginSeqNo == 1` and `EndSeqNo == 0` which is a request for resending all messages. So we want to resend all messages in a sequence from 1 to the latest in response to it.

The feature was initially designed to handle resend request at application level (by detecting message of `MsgType.RESEND_REQUEST` type in `fromAdmin()` methods of a class that implements `quickfix.Application` interface) and send all messages again with proper possible duplicate flags and gap fills.

While testing this we discovered that QuickFIX/J already has a built-in recovery functionality at session level which interferes with our custom implementation. Recovery is implemented by `quickfix.Session` class, the messages of `RESEND_REQUEST` type are detected by `next()` method and are further processed by `nextResendRequest()` method. `nextResendRequest()` tries to retrieve and resend messages from `MessageStorage` or replaces them with Gap Fills if the storage is unable to provide messages.

Now we want to either disable built-in recovery and let our application do the whole job or leverage built-in recovery feature to use our custom message source (Kafka topics).

The problem with disabling is that we see no legitimate way to do it, no settings or customization points. QuickFIX/J session layer seems to be designed for its own automated resend processing only and offers no public API for customization beyond choosing `MessageStorage` implementation.

The problem with using built-in mechanism is that at some point it wants all messages as an `ArrayList` in memory, and this won’t work for 100k-1M volumes, we need an option to stream data.

We see the following options to proceed with the implementation:

**1. Customizing MessageStore for streaming**

Provide a `MessageStore` implementation that relies on data stored in Kafka and retrieves a sequence of messages upon request.
The problem with this option is that the MessageStorage API for retrieving messages is synchronous. It expects to receive a full list of messages for resend in one single block (`ArrayList`), we can't stream messages. This is unacceptable for large volumes because of memory consumption and processing time.

We wonder if we can somehow adjust `MessageStore` to use a visitor-like source that feeds messages.

**2. Customizing session implementation**

Replace `Session` class with a customized version that skips internal resend processing. There is no straightforward way to do it since:

- `Session` is not design to be extended: related methods (`next()` and `nextResendRequest()`) are private.
- Thought there is a `SessionFactory` interface defined, it has only one default implementation and there seems to be no way for replacing `DefaultSessionFactory` with other external alternatives.

Some hacking through reflection could be possible but it won't be an easy way.

**3. Bypassing with exceptions**

Throw some exceptions in methods available at application level to cancel built-in handling at session level. This may possibly work if combined carefully with `RejectMessageOnUnhandledException` setting to tolerate failures in message processing but there is a risk that the framework state will be corrupted or other side effects may show up.

Can you please advise which option is better to use? Or suggest another strategy for implementing recovery of full sequence with 100k-1M messages sourced from Kafka?

Comment: Message recovery is no feature of QuickFIX/J per se but is part of the FIX protocol. Apart from that I would not advise to resend such large volumes of data. Will think about the other points later but does not sound sensible to me.

Comment: Are these messages that you want to resend actually in your message store? To me it sounds like they aren't and you want to misuse the protocol's recovery mechanism. IMHO your design is flawed and you shouldn't resend such large volumes of data. Which kind of messages are these? Are they all of the same message type? Take a look at application level resends.

Comment: @ChristophJohn thank you very much for your comments. The messages are currently not in the message store, as a part of **Option 1** from the post we consider implementing a message store that is connected to existing application-level Kafka storage for reading (other part of the application is responsible for writing). The messages are `TRADE_CAPTURE_REPORT_ACK`, may be some other types also (I'm not sure since I'm still new to the code).

Comment: @ChristophJohn I totally agree that current design looks flawed, that's why I'm seeking for opinion from experts. "Application level resends" sounds like a better solution, where can I find more details on this, could you be kind enough to point it out in code or specification? I still struggle with the structure of specification at https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/ .

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the specification, you were almost at the correct location, but I have to admit that it is a bit tricky to find. From the page that you linked down to "FIX Application Layer" -> FIX Latest -> Infrastructure-> Specification.

https://www.fixtrading.org/online-specification/business-area-infrastructure/

Or more specifically https://www.fixtrading.org/online-specification/business-area-infrastructure/#category-application-sequencing

Some quotes from there which to me sound like exactly the thing you are looking for:

> application sequencing and recovery makes provision for the desired messages – and only the desired messages – to be seamlessly requested and resent while retaining the standard behaviors of the session protocol. It also provides the receiver with the flexibility to put off recovery of application level messages until a slow period or after the market has closed.

> Application sequencing is not something that will be used in a normal order routing scenario. It has more relevance in large volume one-way connections in which the receiver would like to have some ability to control the data that is resent after a disconnect or data loss.

> It should only be used for managing the flow of data when a FIX connection is used to deliver data in bulk...

However, as the name suggests, application level sequencing needs to be implemented in your application, i.e. there is no built-in support in QFJ for this.